# 'srcset' attribute in PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

Does PhantomJS support 'srcset' attribute which belongs to 'img' tag?

I have following function. Chrome returns 'true' while PhantomJS returns 'false'. I just want to make sure if it means that PhantomJS does not support this attribute.

```
function testIfsrcsetImplemented()
{
    return 'srcset' in new Image();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS 1.x is based on a QtWebKit fork from year 2010. It is comparable to Chrome 13. The earliest mention of the srcset attribute that I found is from [2013](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/21/webkit-implements-srcset-and-why-its-a-good-thing/).

PhantomJS 2 also doesn't support this property despite being based on a [newer version](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/PhantomJS-2):

> As of May 2014 it is based on webkit 538.1 (7 months old).

Comment: As I found, Chrome started supporting this attribute from its 34th version. Then, based on your comment we can conclude that PhantomJS 1.9.0 which I am working with, does not support the attribute. Also, does the function, which I shared in my question, check this ability?